# D-Separation in a Bayesian Network

Tags: graph-theory, bayesian, bayesian-network

I am working with the graph below:

[image]

I know the three cases of d-separation are below ([taken from here](http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/eecs/winter2020/cs536/slides/bayesnets3.2pp.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1DBny4MAm5QzUEBpXejPHf_owx9lMcyrCPKMTDFKxf9FsIcxgvzyHQYS8)):
[image]

I need to find ALL pairs of nodes separated by `{A}` and `{A, F}`

My thought is:

`{A} = [ {B, C} because of rule 1, {B, D} because of rule 1, [D, C} because of rule 1 ]`

`{A, F} = [ {B, C} because of rule 1, {B, D} because of rule 1, [D, C} because of rule 1 ]`

I don't think `{A, F}` is correct, but I can't see why not, since `{F}` is just a leaf node and doesn't d-separate anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{A} = [ {B, C} because of rules 1 and 3, {D, C} because of rules 1 and 3 ]`

For a pair of nodes to be d-separated by a set of nodes $S$, **all** paths between these nodes should be blocked by S. That's why `{B, D}` are not d-separated by `{ A }` - there is a direct path between them that is not blocked by $A$.

`{B, C}` are indeed d-separated by `{A}`, but to see that we need to also consider the path $B \rightarrow E \leftarrow C$ which is blocked by case 3. The same goes for `{D, C}` and the path $D \leftarrow B \rightarrow E \leftarrow C$, which is again blocked by case 3 beacuase of $E$.

Now, these last two are actually not blocked by `{A, F}` Because $F$ is a descendant of $E$ and thus unblocks the above paths. Case 3 in your image actually extends to the descendants of E, as well as the node itself, not being observed.

So : `{A, F} = []`